# Running i_386 asm on x86_64 : Reboot instruction

Tags: assembly, x86-64, behavior

I'm trying to run a few asm lines on my 64-bits (Ubuntu 12.04)
Just to execute the reboot syscall.
I can compile it, but when running nothing happends.

Here is the code :

```
section .text
        global _start

_start:
    mov eax,88
    mov ebx,0xfee1dead
    mov ecx,672274793
    mov edx,0x89abcdef
    mov esi,0
    int 0x80
```

I compile it using :

```
nasm -f elf reboot.asm
```

Then I link it using :

```
ld -m elf_i386 -s -o reboot reboot.o
```

I have some questions concerning this behavior :

- If I'm using it correctly, is running this 32bit code on a 64-bit system the origin of the problem ?
- I'm wondering about passing NULL to the %esi register, is this argument wrong for the reboot syscall ?

Answer (score 0):

Need to be superuser to use this system call. You can give the file superuser permissions... as root, "chown root:root myfile", "chmod +s myfile".

You probably want to check the error code, if any, after any `int 80h`...

```
int 80h
test eax, eax
jns good ; shouldn't happen for sys_reboot
neg eax
mov ebx, eax
mov eax, 1 ; __NR_exit
int 80h
```

Now by doing "echo $?", you should be able to see the error number. Look it up in errno.h.

I think zero in esi is okay. Dunno if it'll work on a 64-bit system - "should", I think.

If it works, this results in a "prompt" reboot - same as pulling the plug. It is NOT the same as the "reboot" shell command! I decided it wasn't really what I wanted to do...

Comment: I was already using sudo. I found the error be reading the reboot man. the flag in edx i use now is 0x1234567 and it works !